# Status: 415, error: "Unsupported Media Type" - for POST request OneToMany - ManyToOne relation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, one-to-many, many-to-one

I've been trying to solve this problem for 2 days, I've read everything and tried a lot of options, but nothing happens and I can not see where I'm wrong.
I just have to add a table entry that merges 2 other tables. I apologize for the long description, but I just wanted to be exhaustive
**This is relation between tables**
[image]

**This is my code:**
**User class**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID")
private int id;

@Column(name = "FirstName")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "LastName")
private String lastName;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JsonIgnore
private List<ProductRatings> userGroups = new ArrayList<>();

public User() {}
}
```

**Product class**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;  
import org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch;  
import org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode;  
import javax.persistence.*;  
import javax.validation.constraints.DecimalMax;  
import javax.validation.constraints.DecimalMin;  
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;  
import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.List;  

@Entity  
@Table(name = "products")  
public class Product{  
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID")
private int id;

@Column(name = "Name")
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
@JsonIgnore
private List<ProductRatings> productGroups = new ArrayList<>();

public Product() {}
}
```

**ProductRating class**

```
import javax.persistence.*;  
@Entity  
@Table(name = "product_ratings")  
public class ProductRatings {  

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID")
private int id;

@Column(name = "Rating")
private int rating;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "UserID")
private User user;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "ProductID")
private Product product;

public ProductRatings() {}
}
```

**This is my Postman request**
[image: Post request] 
**This is request status**
[image]
**Ande finaly code in IDEA console**
    2019-03-15 20:44:30.150  WARN 7288 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.teamwork_2.producttag.models.ProductRatings]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': back reference type (java.util.List) not compatible with managed type (com.teamwork_2. producttag.models.Product)

```
2019-03-15 20:44:30.158  WARN 7288 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.teamwork_2. producttag.models. ProductRatings]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': back reference type (java.util.List) not compatible with managed type (com.teamwork_2. producttag.models. Product)   

2019-03-15 20:44:30.174  WARN 7288 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported]
```

Comment: Never use entity classes for data exchange on a rest service. Learn about 3 tier architecture

Comment: I guess you know that I'm learning now and can not know everything

Answer (score 0):

This is due to unexpected input to the REST Client.
Try adding

> Content-Type: application/json

and

> Accept: application/json

in REST Client header section.

I hope it helps.